# NSMutableArray addObject Isn't Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to create a `NSMutableArray` which will become the dataSource for a `UIPickerView`, but nothing is getting added to the array, the console just shows (.  What am I doing wrong?

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFQuery *rejectedNumber = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
    [rejectedNumber findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!objects) {
            // Did not find any UserStats for the current user

            NSLog(@"NotFound");
        } else {

           for (int i=0;i<[objects count];i++)
            {
                PFObject * obj = [objects objectAtIndex:i];
                self.theObject = obj;

                NSString *string = obj[@"GroupName"];
                [arr addObject:string];
                NSLog(@"GOGOGO%@", arr);

            }
```

Comment: What is the value printed in the console.

Comment: @New16 the console prints GOGOGO(

Comment: Have you checked with keeping a breakpoint before this line `[arr addObject:string];`, whats the value of the string. There is something fishy about the string variable. Also, I think it is only executed one time.

Comment: @New16 Here is the full console printout when I add a log for the string along with the Array:

`2016-10-04 22:04:53.106 Share Bibles[27771:4407725] YWAM CR Base
2016-10-04 22:04:53.106 Share Bibles[27771:4407725] GOGOGO(
2016-10-04 22:04:53.107 Share Bibles[27771:4407725] CRICS Teachers
2016-10-04 22:04:53.107 Share Bibles[27771:4407725] GOGOGO(`

Comment: Try declaring the mutable array in this way. `__block NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`. I am completely against this, since you are trying manipulate the array in blocks.

Comment: @New16 No change at all doing that.

Comment: Try this NSLog(@"GOGOGO%@", arr[0]);
And did you check the number element of arr. I think it contains only 1 element "(".

Comment: There's something missing here.  Where's the end of the log?  If the array is actually empty, there should be a closing `)` on the next line.

Comment: Unless ´obj[@"GroupName"]´ has a character which NSLog can't print. If you create a NSString with the ASCII char of hexadecimal code 00 in the middle of it, it not only won't appear but it will also rip off everything after it in the NSLog, however the NSString content is still there.